# How do nested for loops loop over muldimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

This is a bit of an odd question and hard to find an answer for.

Here is the code:

```java
int[][][][] array = new int[3][2][6][8];
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < array[i][j][k].length; n++) {
                array[i][j][k][n] = ++x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening in this line:

```java
array[i][j][k].length
```

More specifically, what I'd like to know why this line `array[i][j][k].length` loops the correct number of times.

To me it looks like it is counting the `[6]` in `new int[3][2][6][8];`
What is the plain English translation for my mind to fully understand it instead of just being able to code it?

I'm just using `array[i][j][k].length` as an example. I could ask the same question for `array[i][j].length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than thinking of `array` here as a multidimensional array `int[][][][]`, think of it as a single dimensional array (of length 3) containing `int[][][]`s.

How do you loop through a single dimensional array? Well,

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each foo in array...
    int[][][] foo = array[i];
    // do something with foo
}
```

Now something will be performed for each `foo` in `array`. Since `foo` is another single dimensional array (of length 2) of `int[][]`s, we can loop over it in the same fashion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each foo in array...
    int[][][] foo = array[i];
    for (int l = 0 ; i < foo.length ; j++) { // for each bar in foo...
        int[][] bar = foo[j];
        // do something with bar...
    }
}
```

`bar` is another single dimensional array (of length 6) containing `int[]`s. Let's loop over that too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each foo in array...
    int[][][] foo = array[i];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < foo.length ; j++) { // for each bar in foo...
        int[][] bar = foo[j];
        for (int k = 0 ; k < bar.length ; k++) { // for each baz in bar...
            int[] baz = bar[k];
            // do something with baz...
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we loop over `baz`, which is a single dimensional array (of length 8) of ints, too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each foo in array...
    int[][][] foo = array[i];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < foo.length ; j++) { // for each bar in foo...
        int[][] bar = foo[j];
        for (int k = 0 ; k < bar.length ; k++) { // for each baz in bar...
            int[] baz = bar[k];
            for (int n = 0 ; n < baz.length ; n++) { // for each number in baz...
                // do something with baz[n]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the "magic". Notice the variable assignments:

```
foo = array[i];
bar = foo[j];
baz = bar[k];
```

If you replace `baz` with `bar[k]`, then replace `bar` with `foo[j]`, then replace `foo` with `array[i]`, deleting the variable declarations as you go, you get the nested for loop in your question!

For example, here's a step by step visualisation for `baz[n]`:

```
baz[n]
bar[k][n] // replace baz with bar[k]
foo[j][k][n] // replace bar with foo[j]
array[i][j][k][n] // replace foo with array[i]
```

This is where `array[i][j][k][n]` comes from!

> To me it looks like it is counting the `[6]` in `new int[3][2][6][8];`

It's actually counting the `[8]`. If you look closely, `array[i][j][k]` corresponds to `baz` here, which has length 8. It might be more useful to count the loops, rather than the indices in the syntax. It's the fourth loop in the nesting, so it's looping over the fourth dimension, which has length 8.

Comment: Thanks! I read this a few times but it finally clicked! Would any issues arise from this type of .length counting? @JohnG posted a comment below in regards to it.

Comment: @A.I  It is problematic if you used `array[0][1][2].length`. The arrays might have different lengths. But in this case they have the same length anyway, as you have specified in the initialisation.

Comment: So if the lengths were dynamic, for example user were to choose lengths, this would have been a problem?

Comment: @A.I I meant that `array[0][1][2].length` could be different from another subarray’s length, like `array[0][1][0].length`. It doesn’t matter whether the user inputs the length or you specified it in code. The point is that different subarrays could have different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

A multidimensional array can be thought of as an array of arrays (which themselves can contain arrays). What distinguishes an array of arrays from a 2D grid is that the "smaller" arrays can be of different lengths. Using `array[i][j][k].length` (for example), only works if each array of the 3rd dimension is the same size. Assuming this is the case, finding the lengths of arrays at different levels will return the sizes of their respective dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `int[][][][] array` is an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of int. So here, for `int[3][2][6][8]`, you have an array of 3 arrays of 2 arrays of 6 arrays of 8 int.

`array[i]` give you the i-th array from your variable named `array`. `array[i][k]` give you the k-th array of the i-th array.

Therefore `array[i][j][k].length` give you the length of the k-th array of the j-th array of the i-th array from your variable named `array`. Here, since you created all the array from `int[3][2][6][8]`,  no matter i, j and k, you will always have the length `8`, since all the arrays from the same dimension all have the same size.

We could add a whole array of 10 int to `array[1][1]`, and then `array[1][1].length` will be `7` and `array[1][1][6].length` will be `ten`.

The most important thing to understand and remember is that **`int[][][][] array` is an array of arrays**. So it loops the correct number of times because you don't get out of the array and his sub-array (and his others nested sub-arrays...) because you always have their lengths and don't go further.